# How to name the all shapes

Tags: vba

I have a presentation with many shapes and want to name each of them as "MyPicture#", where # is a number. For example shape 65 would be named MyPicture65. Can VBA do this? How then?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist:  https://imgflip.com/i/17zbfc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

    Dim sld         As Slide
    Dim shp         As Shape
    Dim lctr        As Long

    For Each sld In ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            lctr = lctr + 1
            shp.Name = "MyPicture" & lctr
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: The code works perfect. However I see now that titles and more also  get the name "MyPicture#". Is there a way to limit only to shapes with external sources?